# How to get '_redirects' to be recognised netlify

Tags: redirect, netlify

I'm currently creating a very basic fictional restaurant website which I am hosting via netlify.

I want to redirect 'zugimdev.netlify.com' to the domain 'zugimdev.tech'. Unfortunately at the moment the '_redirects' file doesn't seem to do anything.

This is the current content of my '_redirects' file.

```
# These rules will change if you change your site’s custom domains or HTTPS settings

# Redirect default Netlify subdomain to primary domain
https://zugimdev.netlify.com/* https://www.zugimdev.tech/:splat 301!
```

Here is a link to my GitHub repository for this site.

https://github.com/Zugim/Sakanamachi

Any help as to why this isn't redirecting correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you mark the question as ✅ if it is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use your custom domain instead of `netlify.com` domain.
Comprehensive Netlify documentation - https://www.netlify.com/docs/custom-domains/

But in a gist what "I" did to add the custom domain was to go to "

## 1. Go to "Domain Settings"

[image: go to domain settings]

## 2. Add your domain

[image: add your domain]

## 3. Enable HTTPS (SSL/TLS certificate)

Scroll down and enable HTTPS

[image: enable https]

---

After setting up your custom domain, you should be able to get to your site using either the Netlify domain or your custom domain.

[image: last demo]

In my case, all of URLs above point to the correct website.

- https://sungcodes.netlify.com
- https://sung.codes/
- https://www.sung.codes/